# How can I port DeviceIOControl to ioctl?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, porting

In my understanding, DeviceIOControl and ioctl are the same functions. They both send control codes to the hardware and return the responses. In an effort to reuse code, I am trying to create a function which will work in a cross-platform manner. Therefore, I've decided to use the DeviceIOControl api since it is fixed and specific. The problem is: how do I map ioctl to that?

I currently have:

```
int DeviceIoControl_issueCommand(DeviceHandle handle, int command, void *input, ssize_t sizeof_input, void *output, ssize_t sizeof_output, uint32_t *bytes_written){
#if SYSTEMINFORMATION_ISWINDOWS
    int result = DeviceIoControl(handle,command,input,sizeof_input,output,sizeof_output,bytes_written,0);
    if (result == 0){
        result = -1; //-1 is the new error return
    }
    return result;
#else
    int result = ioctl(handle, command, input); //this doesnt work!
    return result;
#endif
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found that there is an IOCTL which does pass raw data to and from the driver (at least for the hard drive): HDIO_DRIVE_TASKFILE (http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/ioctl/hdio.txt)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not possible without a **lot** of internal translation in `DeviceIoControl_issueCommand`. The function calls are completely different and expect different parameters and data. You can work around this by declaring an IOControl class and adding member functions for each type of IO functionality you want to support.

```
class IOControl
{
public:
    void DoIoControlX();
    void DoIoControlY(int param1, int param2);
};
```

Then provide an impelementation for each platform you need to support. One for Windows `DeviceIOControl` calls and one for systems that support `ioctl`

Comment: It seems that maybe ioctl is a bit higher level than DeviceIOControl, is there maybe a lower level function? `DeviceIOControl` seems like it simply passes the data to the driver and passes back the result. Is there nothing that can emulate that in linux?

Comment: No, their functionality is synonymous but they operate on different data. The calls are passed down to the device specified by `handle` so it's up to the implementation of the OS subsystem or device driver to handle the call.